# Image align html in jediorpane

Tags: java, html, jeditorpane

I'm working with a jEditorPane right now and I need text to align in the top right of the image and, despite a html tag for align="left" within my image, i am still getting the text in the bottom right of the photo. I know that  a jEditorPane only supports HTML up to 3.2 but I checked and made sure that the  align tag has been used since HTML 1.0

Desired output:

[image: desired output]

Current output:

[image: current output]

here is a code snippet for more information, where `output` is a defined jEditorPane (set to use html) that was already added to the frame:

```
output.setText("<img src=\"https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png\" alt=\"profile picture\" width=\"60\" height=\"60\" align=\"left\"/>\r\n\r\n<font face=\"tahoma\" size=\"3\">\r\n\r\n<b>username</b>\r\n\r\n<font face=\"tahoma\" size=\"2.5\">\r\n<br>\r\n    \"blah blah blah\" \r\n<br>\r\n    \"blah blah blah\" \r\n<br>\r\n    \"blah blah blah\" \r\n</p>\r\n</br>\r\n<hr>");
```

The text in html format:

```html
<img src= "https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" alt= "profile picture" width= "60" height= "60" align= "left"/>

<font face= "tahoma" size= "3">
  
  <b>username</b>
  
  <font face="tahoma" size="2.5">
    <br>
    "blah blah blah" 
    <br>
    "blah blah blah" 
    <br>
    "blah blah blah" 
    </p>
  </br>
<hr>
```

Comment: What's that strange closing `p`-tag doing there? It's never opened. Also, what's up with all the different kinds of line breaks b and \r\n? Finally, you're also using a deprecated attribute `align` and deprecated HTML elements `font` - the latter won't work in HTML5. Finally, to make editing of the HTML easier, I'd use single quotes as wrappers, so you can use doubles in the HTML string. I'm not entirely sure how jEditorPane works, but if it simply outputs HTML, you should not care what jEditorPane supports, but what browsers support.

Comment: The closed `p` is just a typo, I have been moving from notepad to eclispe all day.

\r\n is generated by eclipse windowbuilder which I'm using to have a simpler workspace, it just means new line.

I can use deprecated tags because I am working with only having to support HTML 3.2 and below.

As for the quotes, very excellent idea

Comment: First correct typhos in your html, \r\n are potentially conflictive since not every Operative System uses them for create a new line.

Comment: `\r\n` is interpreted by the java compiler before it is interpreted as html. `\r\n` is just a new line.

`<p>this is a  sentence</p>`

is the same as 

`<p>this is a \r\n sentence</p>`

at runtime

Answer (score 0):

Setting `vertical-align: text-top;` on the text should work if I'm right.

edit; Or in JS `object.style.verticalAlign="top"`

Comment: There isn't any way to use CSS within the jEditorPane ass far as I'm aware, `style` tag doesn't work either sadly. Im stuck with raw HTML that is 3.2 or lower.

Comment: Searched around a bit and found out that you can add a CSS file to jEditorPane so maybe that would be an option: http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/jfc-swing/how-add-style-stylesheet-jeditorpane-example-code

Comment: I just applied it to my program and I couldn't get it to work. I tested it and applied padding to my image which did work but for some reason the text just does not want to go to the top. I am not sure if it's some sort of compatibility issue or what but it won't move. I am testing my html in a browser too and I can get it to work there just not within the frame of my program.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure how jEditorPane works, but if it simply outputs HTML, you should not care what jEditorPane supports, but what browsers support. Following my comment, and assuming that you can (and should?) use HTML5, but have to use inline styles I'd do it like so.

```html
<div>
    <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" alt="profile picture" width="60" height="60">
<span style="font-weight:bold;margin-left:12px">username</span>
</div>

<div style="margin-top:12px">
    <!-- Instead of small you could also use font-size -->
    <small>
        blah blah blah<br>blah blah blah
    </small>
</div>
```

In Java, then, using single quotes as wrappers, and double quotes in the HTML string:

```
output.setText('<div><img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" alt="profile picture" width="60" height="60"><span style="font-weight:bold;margin-left:12px">username</span></div><div style="margin-top:12px"><small>blah blah blah<br>blah blah blah</small></div>');
```

Comment: Because the JFrame never leaves the aspect of the program I don't have to worry about browser compatibility. The frame I am working with doesn't support HTML above 3.2 so I don't have to worry about the dedicated tags. Similarly, the `style` tag is not supported. As for my formatting I know it is bad but I am kind of writing this in a way I can manipulate it later once i figure these bugs out, but I do appreciate the help